# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, exception, compiler-errors, bitbucket-pipelines

I am developing a flutter application.
Not sure what is the reason. It is working fine in local emulator. But in Bitbucket the pipeline is getting failed.

Last week, our Android builds began to fail in the bitbucket and locally with an exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/apple/Documents/olam/olam-eco/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDevDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2663: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

lStar needs compileSdkVersion 31 and I changed the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 and buildToolsVersion to "31.0.0".
After adding these changes it is working fine in emulator but when I pushed the changes to bitbucket the pipeline is getting failed with an exception saying

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_292). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
.......

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my changes and also I couldn't figure out the exception thrown.
Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Same on jitpack